# how to make user input on screen to reflect on click event (js, html)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write html and js codes to make user input to change according to which button user clicks. For example, user enters find/replace values respectively and when they hit the replace button, the user input they initially typed in will change. below is my code which is not working at all..

```
var str = document.getElementById('text').value;
var f = document.getElementById('find').value;
var r = document.getElementById('replace').value;

let rep = str.replace(f, r);
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = rep;

//

<button onclick="funcname()">Replace</button><br>
```

Comment: above is the function with my own name, I just named it funcname to make sense

Comment: `document.getElementById('text'),innerHTML = rep;` change this to `document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = rep;` as you used a comma instead of a dot.... Do Let me know if it works.

Comment: oh sorry for typo.. looks like it isn't the case TT

Comment: Now that we understand and assume this is code inside a function, see answer I've posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `replaceAll` [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
function replace() {
              
  var f = document.getElementById('find').value;
  var r = document.getElementById('replace').value
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
              
  text.textContent = text.textContent.replaceAll(f, r);
  return null;                                                                                                         
}
```

```html
<div id="text">foo</div>
find <input id="find">
<div></>      
replace <input id="replace">
              
              
<button onclick="replace()">Replace</button><br>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but as I hit the replace button the page is just reloaded and all the inputs are gone are... dk what shld I do

Comment: @were - Make sure you are not using a <form> tag. It is not needed in this example.

Comment: @were that sounds like something else in your code

Answer (score 1):

You need to create separate functions for what you are doing. Each button will call the functionality it desires.

Below, I have a paragraph with an id text. We can access it using [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Because it is a text element, we access the value using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

For the input, we need an input element which has the id input. The value is accessed using [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-value).

The replace is straight forward, set the innerHTML of the paragraph to the value of the input.

The find, not sure exactly what you wanted, but we can use [string.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to find out whether the value in the input appears in the innerHTML of the paragraph.

Finally, there is find and replace, which can be solved with [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for replacing the first occurance, or you can change to [string.replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to replace all occurances.

```js
const find = function() {
  let str = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
  let inp = document.getElementById('findInput').value;
  
  let matched = str.includes(inp) ? 'was' : 'was not';
  alert(`${inp} ${matched} found in the sentence.`);
};

const replace = function() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('replaceInput').value;
};

const findAndReplace = function() {
  let str = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
  let f = document.getElementById('findInput').value;
  let r = document.getElementById('replaceInput').value;
  
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = str.replace(f, r);
};
```

```html
<p id="text">She sells sea shells on the sea shore.</p>
<label for="findInput">Find:</label> <input id="findInput" type="text"><br>
<label for="replaceInput">Repalce:</label> <input id="replaceInput" type="text"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="find()">Find</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="replace()">Replace</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="findAndReplace()">Find and Replace</button><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that `replace()` only replaces the first occurrence in the `string`, which is causing the issue.

There are two solutions for this issue, which are both very similar.

---

The first solution is to use [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll). This is a new feature introduced in ES2021, which means that it doesn't support old browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer).

To use it, simply use the code below.

```js
const rep = str.replaceAll(f, r); // This line has been modified
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = rep;
```

It will use the new method (`replaceAll()`), which will replace *all* occurrences of `f` with `r`.

---

The second solution uses a similar, yet older function, called [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). It is the same function that you are using, but we are going to use a different technique.

To replace all occurrences, you need to use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to modify the behaviour.

Use the code below to replace all occurrences with `replace()`.

```js
const rep = str.replace(new RegExp(`${f}`, "g"), r); // This line has been modified
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = rep;
```

This uses the `new RegExp` constructor to create a new RegExp instance. This is because we want to pass in a variable.

The second parameter is where the magic happens. The `g` means `global`. This makes the `replace()` method replace all of the occurrences.

---

In summary, both of these methods should work. Here are some circumstances of which one you should use.

- Option 1: Use when targeting newer browsers, and are focused on readability.
- Option 2: Use when targeting older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

try NOT to use `,` instead of `.` because js isnt defining `,` and also if that doesnt work then try using `const replacer = document.querySelector("#text");`.`.replace` only replaces the first selected word so you should try `.replaceAll` instead

Comment: You should remove your first part about replacing `,` with `.`. OP's question has been updated.